# New frame display exception after ListView SelectionChange method uwp c#

Tags: c#, list, win-universal-app

There is a ContestListView with elements:

```
public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        List<int> list = new List<int>();
        list.Add(2);
        list.Add(3);
        list.Add(5);
        list.Add(7);

        ContestListView.ItemsSource = list;
    }
```

I want to navigate to another Frame when SelectionChange is.

```
private void ContestSelectionChange(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(BlankPage1));
    }
```

But I have a problem - sometimes, when I choose element at list, the BlankPage1 starts load, but I got an unhandled exception

> {"Unspecified error\r\n\r\nUnspecified error\r\n"}

at this place

```
#if DEBUG && !DISABLE_XAML_GENERATED_BREAK_ON_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION
        UnhandledException += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
        };
#endif
```

This exception can be after first SelectionChandeg, but it can be too after second, third etc. 
There is BlankPage1 XAML:

```
<Page
x:Class="Contests.BlankPage1"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:Contests"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Page.TopAppBar>
    <CommandBar Foreground="White">
        <CommandBar.Background>
            <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="Assets/app02_0013_panel_main.png"/>
        </CommandBar.Background>
        <CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>
            <AppBarButton Label="LogOut" Click="onClick"/>
        </CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>
    </CommandBar>
</Page.TopAppBar>

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <ScrollViewer>
        <RelativePanel>
            <TextBlock x:Name="txtContestName" 
                               Text="TestTest " 
                               Foreground="DarkOliveGreen" 
                               RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"
                       RelativePanel.Below=""
                               TextWrapping="Wrap"
                               FontSize="20"
                               Margin="5,10,0,10"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="CategoryExpiration" FontSize="12"
                               RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"
                               RelativePanel.Below="txtContestName"
                               Margin="5,0,0,10">
                        <Run x:Name="txtCategory" Text="Test "/>
                        <Run x:Name="txtExpiration" Text="2016-05-23" Foreground="Green"/>
            </TextBlock>
            <RelativePanel x:Name="QuestionPanel" RelativePanel.Below="CategoryExpiration" 
                                   RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"
                                   RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True"
                                   Background="Green"
                                   Margin="5,0,5,5">
                <TextBlock x:Name="textblock1" Text="Question:" Foreground="White"
                                   RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"
                                   Margin="5,5,5,0"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="txtQuestion" Foreground="White"
                                   Text="Test?"
                                   RelativePanel.AlignHorizontalCenterWithPanel="True"
                                   RelativePanel.Below="textblock1"
                                   TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                   Margin="10, 5" TextAlignment="Center"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="AnswerText" PlaceholderText="Test"
                                 RelativePanel.Below="txtQuestion"
                                 RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True"
                                 RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"
                                 Margin="5,5"/>
                <Button x:Name="bSendAnswer" Content="Test"
                                RelativePanel.Below="AnswerText"
                                RelativePanel.AlignHorizontalCenterWithPanel="True"
                                Foreground="White"
                                Margin="5,5" Width="335"/>
            </RelativePanel>
            <RelativePanel x:Name="OrgPanel" RelativePanel.Below="QuestionPanel"
                           RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"
                           RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True"
                           Margin="5,0,5,5" BorderBrush="Gray">
                <TextBlock x:Name="textblock2" Text="Organizator" Foreground="Green"
                                   RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"
                                   Margin="5,5,5,0"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="Org" Text="Test"
                                 RelativePanel.Below="textblock2"
                                 Foreground="DarkGreen"
                                 FontSize="12"
                                 RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True"
                                 RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"
                                 Margin="5,5"/>
            </RelativePanel>
            <RelativePanel x:Name="DesriptionPanel" RelativePanel.Below="OrgPanel"
                           RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"
                           RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True"
                           Margin="5,0,5,5" BorderBrush="Gray">
                <TextBlock x:Name="textblock3" Text="Opis konkursu" Foreground="Green"
                                   RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"
                                   Margin="5,5,5,0"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="txtDescription" Text="test"
                                 RelativePanel.Below="textblock3"
                                 TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                 Foreground="DarkGreen"
                                 FontSize="12"
                                 RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True"
                                 RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"
                                 Margin="5,5"/>
            </RelativePanel>
            <RelativePanel x:Name="PrizePanel" RelativePanel.Below="DesriptionPanel"
                           RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"
                           RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True"
                           Margin="5,0,5,5" BorderBrush="Gray">
                <TextBlock x:Name="textblock4" Text="Test" Foreground="Green"
                                   RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"
                                   Margin="5,5,5,0"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="txtPrize" Text=""
                                 RelativePanel.Below="textblock4"
                                 Foreground="DarkGreen"
                                 TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                 FontSize="12"
                                 RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True"
                                 RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"
                                 Margin="5,5"/>
            </RelativePanel>




        </RelativePanel>
    </ScrollViewer>

</Grid>
```

What my problem is?

Comment: Can you try isolating the issue, get the minimal possible repro?

Comment: I even can't find a place where error is by debugging. It is going after  close bracket at the ContestSelectionChange method.

Comment: What is the stack trace for the exception saying?

Comment: I tried to reproduce your error - I added Listview and SelectionChange event but everything is working correctly. Is this all the code that you have?

Comment: The error message sounds to me more like there are bugs in your `BlankPage1`, please post your `BlankPage1` xaml code and its code behind.

Comment: I have add my XAML code